# Highlighting area between two curves in excel

Tags: excel, graph

[image]

What I need to do is to highlight the area between the two curves to sort of show like a region of values most like and least likely. How can I acieve this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This link is probably what you need.  Too much to summarise but the concept (from the article) is

> The protocol for filling between two plotted lines is pretty much the
>   same as above. We start with two XY scatter chart series, one above
>   and one below the filled area. We will also need two stacked area
>   chart series, one for the clear region below the lower XY line, and
>   one stacked on top to fill between the XY lines

Scroll down to find the section [Fill Between Two XY Series](http://peltiertech.com/fill-under-between-series-in-excel-chart/)

Answer (score -1):

you will need to have three loops: first is to loop X axis where you have min and max values.Lets say A nd B columns. Another two is to loop all cells in excel horizontally and vertically to check if it is between max and min.

```
Sub RunCheck()

Dim lastcell As Long
Dim lastcellData As Long
Dim MinVal As Integer
Dim MixVal As Integer

    'lets assume that we have array in A2-... for min and B2-... for max
    ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Select 
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select

    lastcell = Selection.Cells.Row

    'lets assume that we have data in D to G column and 2 to 20 lines 
    ActiveSheet.Range("D2").Select 
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select

    lastcellData = Selection.Cells.Row


    For E = 2 To lastcell

    MinVal = Cells(E, 2).Value
    MaxVal = Cells(E,3).Value



    FOR P = 2 to lastcellData 

        FOR S = 4 to 7

            IF Cells(p, s) > MinVal  AND    Cells(p, s) < MaxVal Then
            Cells(p, s).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 25)
            End IF

        S = S + 1 
        NEXT S

    P = P + 1
    NEXT P

    E = E + 1
    Next E

End Sub
```